# Change number of month to month name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string like this: `2017-12-01 08:44:49` and I want to get just name of the month from the string.

What I have done:

```
var myMonth = '2017-12-01 08:44:49';
var str = myMonth.substring(5,7);

var months = [
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
    'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
    'October', 'November', 'December'
];
```

I don't know how to attribute this value (ie. 12) to months (I don't want to create 12 if conditionals).

Comment: `months[str - 1]` - Arrays are 0 index so 12 would return `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the month name as `months[str-1]` as array index starts from `0` to `length-1`

```js
var myMonth = '2017-12-01 08:44:49';
var str = myMonth.substring(5,7);

var months = [
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
    'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
    'October', 'November', 'December'
];

console.log(months[str-1]);
```

or otherwise if you don't want to store it in array you can do it like this

```js
var date = new Date("2017-12-01 08:44:49");

var monthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "long" }).format;
var longName = monthName(date);
console.log(longName);
```

Comment: and what to do when date is a variable with arrays of dates and i want to get a new array with for example ['january', 'may', 'april']

Answer (score 5):

Try the following with ECMAScript Internationalization API:

```js
var myMonth = '2017-12-01 08:44:49';
var myDate = new Date(myMonth);
var month = myDate.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });
console.log(month)
```

Where "long" uses the full name of the month.

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to first obtain a date object from the date string (`myMonth`):

```
var myMonth = '2017-12-01 08:44:49';
var aDate = new Date(myMonth.substr(0, 'yyyy-mm-dd'.length)); // 2017-12-01
```

Then get the month number (0-11):

```
var monthNumber = aDate.getMonth();

console.log(months[monthNumber]); // December
```